# Loading two different arrays into tableview (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, uitableview, swift5

I have two functions, one that fetches all my posts and another that fetches guest posts that I'm using Firebase to pull. I'm looking to combine both of these functions into my tableview. What's the best way to do this?

```
var postArray = [Post]() //main array that feeds into tableview
var myArray = [Post]()
var guestArray = [Post]()
var DatabaseConnect = AuthenticationService()

private func fetchAllPosts() {
    self.DatabaseConnect.fetchMyPosts {(myposts) in
        self.DatabaseConnect.fetchGuestPosts {(posts) in
            self.myArray = myposts
            self.guestArray = posts
            self.postArray = self.myArray + self.guestArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with the question is that we don't know what DatabaseConnect does and the question is a bit vague. We also don't know if your using the RTDB or Firestore. It sounds like you're loading data from Firebase and populating an array then reading more data from firebase and appending that to the array. But that's not really clear. It's also not clear what you have all of those class array vars but you're not really using them as class vars. Can you clarify the question and explain what the code is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you make it better.

1. Don't use `self` where it's not required. Eg: `self.DatabaseConnect`.
2. Use DispatchGroup() for simultaneous API calls that are unrelated.
3. Don't use unnecessary variables `myArray` and `guestArray` used only to append to main array why not append it directly.
4. Use `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` for sync background tasks.

Here's the code:

```
var postArray = [Post]() //main array that feeds into tableview
var DatabaseConnect = AuthenticationService()

private func fetchAllPosts() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    postArray = []

    group.enter()
    DatabaseConnect.fetchMyPosts { [weak self] myposts in
        self?.postArray.append(contentsOf: myposts)
        group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    DatabaseConnect.fetchGuestPosts { [weak self] guestPosts in
        self?.postArray.append(contentsOf: guestPosts)
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't seem to work though. Once it hits group.leave, the postArray seems to be cleared

Comment: I've made a few edits to add a few things that I left out. Check once again.

Comment: Still doesn't work. When I print postArray after the first group.leave, it shows up but when I print postArray after the second group.leave, the first fetchMyPosts array doesn't show up.

Comment: try using breakpoints to understand the work-flow and use print statements before `leave()` not after.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reload the tableview twice:

```
   private func fetchAllPosts() {
        self.DatabaseConnect.fetchMyPosts {(myposts) in
            self.postArray.append(myposts)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        self.DatabaseConnect.fetchGuestPosts {(guestPosts) in
            self.postArray.append(guestPosts)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because I want to be able to sort the posts by date afterwards - is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your original code wasn't sorting posts either.. is there a date variable within Post? Have you written any code to sort yet?

Comment: Yes, I was planning to add self.postArray.sort { $0.postDate > $1.postDate } but dont know where to put it in your code. If I add the sort after the second postArray, the initial load won't sort both myposts and guestposts, only the guestPosts.

Comment: Try adding it twice right before each reloadData. It should be self.postArray = self.postArray.sort { $0.postDate > $1.postDate }